# retrieve value from session in laravel route

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-routing

in route cats/create,I post a form with a validation.it will redirect to cats/create if don't accord with the regulation.I want to retrieve the  $validation_result->messages() in action of cats/create.Will these be possible?the result of dd($message) is null:

```
Route::get('cats/create', function() {
$message=Session::get('message');
dd($message);
if($message->has('name')){    
foreach ($message->get('name') as $messageone){
echo $messageone;
  }
}
$cat = new Cat;
return View::make('cats.edit')
                ->with('cat', $cat)
                ->with('method', 'post');
});


Route::post('cats', function() {

$rules = array(
    'name' => 'required|min:3', // Required, > 3 characters
    'date_of_birth' => array('required', 'date') // Must be a date
);
$formresult=Input::all();

$validation_result = Validator::make($formresult,$rules);

if($validation_result->fails()){
    return Redirect::back()->with('message', $validation_result->messages());
}else{

$cat = Cat::create($formresult);
$cat->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
if ($cat->save()) {
    return Redirect::to('cats/' . $cat->id)
                    ->with('message', 'Successfully created profile!');
} else {
    return Redirect::back()
                    ->with('error', 'Could not create profile');
}
}
});
```

but when I retrieve data from session in blade file,it is possible:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
{{Session::get('message')}}
</div>
@endif
```

why? I cannot understand about this.

Comment: You should really use Route::resource('prefix', 'Controller') with a CatController.
This will end up to an unmaintainable website. Why cannot you passes the messages to the View ? And display them from the view ?

Comment: in my way,could laravel be possible to implement?why the message in session is null while I can use {{Session::get('message')}} in bladed?

Comment: Routes are the first access point of your 'public' app. Laravel has not yet had time to set 'errors'.
By the way the variable $errors is passing to the view by the very handful method View::share();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe I saw wrong somethings，it work now！

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition from

```
if($validation_result->fails()){
return Redirect::back()->with('message', $validation_result->messages());
}
```

to

```
if($validation_result->fails())
{
$message = $validation_result->messages();
return Redirect::back()->with('message',$message);
}
```